# program only prints last string of input file

Tags: io, go

i am trying to create a simple program to read lines from a text file and print them out to the console in golang. I spent lots of time going over my code and I simply can't understand why only the last line is being printed out to the screen. can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here? Everything here should compile and run.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func Readln(r *bufio.Reader) (string, error) {
    var (
        isPrefix bool  = true
        err      error = nil
        line, ln []byte
    )
    for isPrefix && err == nil {
        line, isPrefix, err = r.ReadLine()
        ln = append(ln, line...)
    }
    return string(ln), err
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("tickers.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    s, e := Readln(r)
    for e == nil {
        fmt.Println(s)
        s, e = Readln(r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the problem you're seeing?  I downloaded and ran your program and it seems to behave correctly for the data I gave it.  Even when I made sure my lines would exceed the length of the buffer.

Comment: I have a text file of about 100 strings and only the last line of the text file shows on the console. I want essentially duplicate the text file to the screen. Instead only the last string shows.

Comment: What are the line ending characters in your file?  You can use http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm to get a look into the actual file encoding and then add that to your question which will help with others testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I therefore suspect that the problem is in your `tickers.txt` file line endings.   The docs for ReadLine() also indicate that for most situations a Scanner is more suitable.

The following SO question has some useful information for alternative implementations: [reading file line by line in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-file-line-by-line-in-go)

I then used the example in the above question to re-implement your main function as follows:

```
f, err := os.Open("tickers.txt")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I adjusted the poster's program to add some extra debug output, and it definitely reads the file in lines.  And the `isPrefix` part seems to work correctly when I adjusted the buffer to be shorter than the lines I had: it is set to true if a partial line is returned, rather than a line other than the final one.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, you are right, I had already edited the example when I added the debug.  So it is reading line by line.  Have edited my answer.