# How to reduce memory usage of []string?

Tags: go

Go is pretty new to me and i have some troubles understanding the memory usage :

I want to load a file similar to csv into an array of rows, each row being a struct composed of a key on 22 char and an array of values (string).
My code look like this : https://play.golang.org/p/hJ4SHjVXaG

Problem is that for a file of 450M it uses around 2G1 of memory.
Does anyone have a solution to reduce that memory use ?

Update using SirDarius solution : https://play.golang.org/p/DBmOFOkZdx still use around 1G9

Comment: What problem do you what to solve with your program? Memory reducing techniques may be very different and depend on problem class.

Comment: Read file line by line. Recipe is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758113/1975086

Comment: Do you need everything in memory at once? Can't you just process the file line-by-line as @AlexanderTrakhimenok suggested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How many lines and fields are there in the file?

It is plausible that what you are describing is using the minimum amount of memory.

Looking at the code I think it will use 450MB of memory for the underlying string data.

It will then slice that up into strings. These consist of a pointer and a length which take 16 bytes on a 64 bit platform.

So 1.5GB/16 = 93Million.

So if there are >50 Million fields in your file then the memory use seems reasonable.

There are other overheads like number of rows etc so this isn't an exact calculation.

**EDIT**

Given
5 millions row, 10 column each

That is 50 million string headers of 16 bytes which will take 800MB. Plus the data itself 450MB, plus 5 * 8 * 5 million Rows = 200MB makes 1.45GB

So I don't think even with perfect memory allocation, you'll be able to reduce the usage below 1.5GB.

Comment: 5 millions row, 10 column each

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty inefficient to me:

```
for _, value := range strings.Split(line[23:], ";") {
    row.Values = append(row.Values, value)
}
```

You basically obtain a `[]string` by calling the `string.Split` function, and then loop over that slice to append every string to another initially nil string slice.

Why not just do:

```
row.Values = strings.Split(line[23:], ";")
```

instead ?

Though I can't guarantee it, it might be possible that the loop causes each string to be copied, and therefore make your program use twice as memory as needed.

Comment: Indeed, it's pretty useless, i had some validity check in that loop but i can postpone them. 

I just tried, it get down to 1g9, not perfect but already better ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You are appending into a `Row` struct the values obtained by each iteration, which considering the huge file size is not a reasonable good approach. Why your are not processing the file in batches?

Looking at the [Split](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) function it returns a slice of substrings, so it's not necessary to range over the resulted slices and append them into the `row.Values`. You can assign the resulted values directly to `row.Values`, then append it to the `rows` slice.

```
func Split(s, sep string) []string
```

> Split slices s into all substrings separated by sep and returns a
>   slice of the substrings between those separators. If sep is empty,
>   Split splits after each UTF-8 sequence. It is equivalent to SplitN
>   with a count of -1.

```
row.Values = strings.Split(line[23:], ";")
rows = append(rows, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it's about append() function. From language spec

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array

Size of this newly allocated array can be sufficient enough to consume even more further appends. So to allocate precisely you should `slice := make([]Row, 0, WithExpectedCapacity)` and than assign `slice[n]=` instead of `append()`. If you can't do this, you at least can try reflection to compact

```
reflect.ValueOf(&slice).Elem().SetCap(len(slice))
```

Some tricky, but you can see https://play.golang.org/p/LslkOBCvII it works.

Comment: I know the size of the file I use for my test,so I tried to set manually the capacity of each array, but with no big result ...
So I guess it won't change much since i wasn't using the append but i'll try !