# Read the final line in a text file

Tags: go, file-io

I am currently learning Go, and I need to read the final line in a text file.

I have searched everywhere and there does not seem to be a definitive explanation on how one would do this.

How would I do this?

Comment: It's the same concept in any language. Are you asking you to scan a file by lines? https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines

Comment: @JimB That is correct. Could you perhaps offer an explanation in Go?

Comment: What question do you have about the example given, or other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-file-line-by-line-in-go/16615559#16615559?

Comment: @JimB Where in that code returns the final line of the file. I'm still a bit confused about how to get that information.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to state it, the last line you read will be the final line.

Comment: @JimB But how do I catch that?

Comment: you assign it to a variable: https://play.golang.org/p/6mCIJDW2jy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting the search from the very beginning of the file can be an expensive option esp. if your file(s) are large.

A better option may be to - Use os.Open to open the file and stat method (https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat) to get the size of the file. Start reading from end of the file using ReadAt (https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.ReadAt - read the last byte first, second last byte next..), all the way reverse till you find the second newline character. That's the beginning of the last line. Hope this helps.