# Processing a file byte by byte in go

Tags: file, go, io, character, byte

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-go/16615559#16615559), what is the idiomatic way to process a file one byte at a time in go?

Put another way, is there a better way to write the following?

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
file_string = string(file)
for i, c := range file_string {
    // -snip-
}
```

Comment: This isn't reading the file one byte at a time. This is reading the whole file, converting it to a string, and iterating through it rune by rune (not byte by byte). Do you want to read the file one byte at a time, or process it one byte at a time?

Comment: Reading one byte at a time is extremely inefficient, you probably want something like: [`Reader.ReadByte`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio?tab=doc#Reader.ReadByte)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading the entire file as a string (not bytes) at once, then processing it rune-by-rune (not byte-by-byte). To literally read the file one byte at a time (which is **very likely not what you want**), you must do exactly that:

```
f, err := os.Open("path")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

b := make([]byte, 1)

for {
    err := f.Read(b)
    if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
        fmt.Println(err)
        break
    }

    // process the one byte b[0]

    if err != nil {
        // end of file
        break
    }
}
```

However, what you more likely want is to read the file efficiently, and *process* it one byte at a time. For this, you should use a [buffered reader](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio):

```
f, err := os.Open("path")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

br := bufio.NewReader(f)

// infinite loop
for {

    b,err := br.ReadByte()

    if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
        fmt.Println(err)
        break
    }

    // process the one byte b

    if err != nil {
        // end of file
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: This for-loop is not working: expected boolean or range expression, found assignment (missing parentheses around composite literal?)

Comment: `for b, err := binFileReader.ReadByte(); err == nil; {
   fmt.Println(b)
  }`  Something like this is needed I think