# How to use fmt.Sscan to parse integers into an array?

Tags: go

I'm trying to scan a list of integers from a string into an array (or alternatively, a slice)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var nums [5]int
    n, _ := fmt.Sscan("1 2 3 4 5", &nums)  // doesn't work
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

What do I need to pass as second argument to `Sscan` in order for this to work?

I know I could pass `nums[0], nums[1] ...` etc., but I'd prefer a single argument.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862443/golang-is-there-a-better-way-read-a-file-of-integers-into-an-array

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible as a convenient one-liner. As `Sscan` takes `...interface{}`, you would need to pass slice of interfaces as well, hence converting your array first:

```
func main() {
    var nums [5]int

    // Convert to interfaces
    xnums := make([]interface{}, len(nums))
    for n := range nums {
        xnums[n] = &nums[n]
    }

    n, err := fmt.Sscan("1 2 3 4 5", xnums...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("field %d: %s\n", n+1, err)
    }

    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/1X28J7JJwl

Obviously you could mix different types in your interface array, so it would make the scanning of more complex string easier. For simply space-limited integers, you might be better using `strings.Split` or `bufio.Scanner` along with `strconv.Atoi`.

Comment: I like this answer, it uses Sscan's reflection cleverly. You can change `var nums [5]int` to `var nums [5]string` and it still works :-) . Also, it returns *sort of* sensible values for silly input! See http://play.golang.org/p/sWapMMVTcM. Only problem is possibly the use of `0` for invalid input when it's `[5]int`. `strconv.Atoi` is probably therefore recommended.

Comment: @Intermernet, you obviously still have error checking within `Sccan`, I should've checked for the returned errors in my answer really. See a modified example of yours: http://play.golang.org/p/F2werhtqdU [updated my answer to reflect this!]

Comment: Yes, I was being picky :-) I learnt a good shortcut from your answer, so thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

To allow this to work on more than just hard-coded strings, it's probably better to use a [`bufio.Scanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner), and an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) interface to do this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func scanInts(r io.Reader) ([]int, error) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    var ints []int
    for s.Scan() {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(s.Text())
        if err != nil {
            return ints, err
        }
        ints = append(ints, i)
    }
    return ints, s.Err()
}

func main() {
    input := "1 2 3 4 5"
    ints, err := scanInts(strings.NewReader(input))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ints)
}
```

Produces:

> [1 2 3 4 5]

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/rUIJvRiiTK)

Comment: Thank you. This looks a little too complex for my simple use case, but I learned some new things (still in the beginner phase with go, as you might have guessed from the question).

Comment: @JohannesCharra No problem, the important bit that you will  probably need to remember, is that the string may not contain just integers, and your code needs to take that into account. `strconv.Atoi` will check that the  next "thing" can be converted to an integer, and if not, it will return an error. You should use it, whatever solution you end up adopting for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're trying to use Sscann specifically you can also try this as an alternative:

- split the input string by spaces
- iterate the resulting array
- convert each string into an int
- store the resulting value into an int slice

Like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    nums := make([]int, 0)
    for _, s := range strings.Split("1 2 3 4 5", " ") {
        i, e := strconv.Atoi(s)
        if e != nil {
            i = 0 // that was not a number, default to 0
        }
        nums = append(nums, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/rCZl46Ixd4

Comment: Probably the most straightforward solution, which I was already aware of but tried to simplify further. Thanks.