# how to declare a function accept an array of interface in golang?

Tags: go

I want to declare a function accept array of interface, such as this:

```
func (this *CvStoreServiceImpl) setItemList(coll *mgo.Collection, itemList ...interface{}) (err error)
```

Howerver, when I call this function like as follow failed:

```
jobList := cvRaw.GetJobList()
this.setItemList(jobColl, jobList...)
```

here this the error:

```
cannot use cvRaw.GetJobList() (type []*cv_type.CvJobItemRaw) as type []interface {} in argument to this.setItemList
```

Comment: Go has no covariant types. You need to stuff your items in jobList into a []interface{} first before passing the []interface{} to your function. BTW. Don't use interface{}.

Comment: @Volker why not `interface{}` ?

Comment: @Volker and what is difference between my code and this [mgo insert method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L1823)

Comment: Remove "..." 3 dots from "this.setItemList(jobColl, jobList...)", it should be this.setItemList(jobColl, jobList), jobList is already an array

Comment: @PrashantThakkar that is not right, jobList will become just one parameter, such as `[3, 4, 5]`, if without `....`, it becomes `[[3, 4, 5]] `

Comment: I remember in the past someone had a similar problem with `fmt.Sscan`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28604563/847869

Comment: This is a quite common golang gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for [is this](http://play.golang.org/p/MjSUMFYs22)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    interfacetious := []interface{}{"s", 123, float64(999)}
    stuff(interfacetious)
    stuff2(interfacetious...)

    stuff2("or", 123, "separate", float64(99), "values")
}

// Stuff can only work with slice of things
func stuff(s []interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

// Stuff2 is polyvaridc and can handle individual vars, or a slice with ...
func stuff2(s ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question correctly declares the `setItemList` method, assuming that you want a variadic argument. Because the `setList` function works with any Mongo document type, it is appropriate to use `interface{}` in this scenario.

A `[]*cv_type.CvJobItemRaw` cannot be converted to a `[]interface{}`.  Write a loop to create the `[]interface{}` from `jobList`.

```
jobList := cvRaw.GetJobList()
s := make([]interface{}, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = v
}
this.setItemList(jobColl, s...)
```

See the [Go Language FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) for more details.