# Golang: Strings Trim Function

Tags: string, go, trim

I used `strings.Trim()` in Golang to trim the first five characters.
However, the last "a" is always gone.
Why is that so?

Example:

```
sentence := "Kab. Kolaka Utara"
result := strings.Trim(sentence,sentence[:4])
fmt.Println(result)
```

Result: `Kolaka Utar`

I expected: `Kolaka Utara`

https://play.golang.org/p/R6UoKWNaVv

Comment: What is your expected output, for example: "Kolaka Utara" ?

Comment: @Amd Yes, I expected Kolaka Utara

Comment: For googlers who just want to trim spaces from a string (the standard definition of "trim"), `strings.Trim(s, " ")` for spaces only or `strings.TrimSpace(s)` for all whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Trim returns a slice of the string s with all leading and trailing Unicode code points contained in cutset removed.

`sentence[:4]` is `"Kab."` Trim will remove all leading and trailing `"k"`, `"a"`, `"b"`, `"."`.

https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Trim

Answer (score 4):

If you want to trim the first 5 bytes, then use:

```
result := sentence[5:]
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/mWjAQ3kgLY)

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are UTF-8 encoded in Golang for **single byte Unicode code points**  you may use `result := sentence[5:]`
like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sentence := "Kab. Kolaka Utara"
    result := sentence[5:]
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

output:

```
Kolaka Utara
```

and for multibyte Unicode code points like `"µµµµ Kolaka Utara"` you may use `string([]rune(sentence)[5:])`, like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sentence := "µµµµ Kolaka Utara"
    result := string([]rune(sentence)[5:])
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

output:

```
Kolaka Utara
```

and see Docs:

`func Trim(s string, cutset string) string`:

> Trim returns a slice of the string s with all leading and trailing
>   Unicode code points contained in cutset removed.

and see: [Extracting substrings in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311033/extracting-substrings-in-go)

Answer (score 1):

You should know the precise meaning of "trim" in programming: removing some characters both from the beginning and the end.

And in Golang's strings.Trim, The second argument is a set of characters.

Trim will remove all leading and trailing characters contained in the set.

In your example:

The set is

```
{"K", "a", ".", "b"};
```

For "Kab. Kolaka Utara", Trim will remove "Kab." from the beginning and "a" from the end.

So, the actual string you get is " Kolaka Utar" instead of "Kolaka Utar" which has no leading space.

If you just want to "trim" the first five characters, you should use this statement:

```
sentence = sentence[5:].
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about how many characters to be trimmed. Use this method.

```
func main() {
    sentence := "Kab. Kolaka Utara"
    fmt.Println(sentence)
    fmt.Println(sentence[5:len(sentence)])

}
```

Output :

```
 Value :  Kab. Kolaka Utara
 Trimed : Kolaka Utara
```